# Populating combobox inside a listbox datatemplate based on another combox's selected item in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In my wpf application, I have a `Listbox` control. `Listbox` control can have multiple rows. Inside the Listbox's `DataTemplate` I have two `dropdowns` in each row. For brevity,

```
<Listbox>
 <ItemTemplate>
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type someModel}">
 <Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition/>
<ColumnDefinition/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Name="ComboBox1" ItemSource="{Binding listData}">  
    </ComboBox>  
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Name="ComboBox2" ItemSource="{Binding listData2}">  
    </ComboBox>  
</Grid
 </DataTemplate>
</ItemTemplate>
</Listbox>
```

My question is how can I update the `ItemSource` of `ComboBox1` based on the selection of `ComboBox2` of a particular row in the list?

See the picture below for more clarification about the requirement:
[image]

Comment: bind the `SelectedValue` to a viewmodel property, in its `set`, update `listData`

Comment: I know that :), but wanted to know the way of tracking row

Comment: `SelectedValue` is in specific row.

Comment: How is that picture supposed to bring "clarification about the requirement"?

Comment: May be you can read the description before the picture and then focus on the picture? If still not I can make it clear for you @mm8